# custom httpError is throwing 500 internal server error in WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7, web-config, http-error

I am trying to add my custom error handling for http errors that are thrown after requests to my WCF API.
I have added the below in my web.config:

```
<security> 
   <requestFiltering> 
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10000" /> 
   </requestFiltering> 
</security> 

<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" > 
   <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode='-1' /> 
   <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/GlobalHttpError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> 
   <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode='-1' /> 
   <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/GlobalHttpError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> 
   <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode='-1' /> 
   <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/GlobalHttpError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> 
   <remove statusCode="411" subStatusCode='-1' /> 
   <error statusCode="411" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/GlobalHttpError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> 
   <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode='-1' /> 
   <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/GlobalHttpError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> 
</httpErrors>
```

I have a method that uploads files so I am trying to generate a custom error page once the file size exceeds the maxAllowedContentLength.

Whenever I add this piece of code to my web.config and I try to test the method from postman I get 500 error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

What is this error and how can I resolve it?

**Update**

I tried also the below:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" > 
       <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode='13' /> 
       <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode='13' prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/GlobalHttpError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> 
    </httpErrors>
```

But still not working

Even if I add this only:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
```

Also same error is thrown when maxAllowedContentLength is exceeded.

Comment: Check IIS log files to read the substatus please, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: @LexLi thak you for your reply; substatuscode is 13 for 404, are you suggesting to specify the substatus and remove other custom errors? Others are not thrown

Comment: @LexLi I please check my update.

Comment: I mean reading IIS log files to check the sub status of that 500 error.